# determine the particular kind of constructor for an ADT in rascal

Tags: rascal

The problem is as follows:

```
data Scalar=type1()|type2()|...

data Expr=scalar(Scalar aType)| secondForm(..) | thirdForm(..) |..

case Expr ee:binaryOperation(Expr e1,Expr e2, Op opern):
    //do something useful
```

How can I specify the condition to determine the type of e1 and e2, and take actions henceforth, for example,

```
    if(e1 != scalar(_)) //do something useful
    if(e2 != scalar(_)) //do something useful
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have (at least) three options.

First, you can include that in the case:

```
case Expr ee:binaryOperation(Expr e1:scalar(_), Expr e2, Op opern) :
```

In that case, you would need a second, more general case for when `e1` is not a `scalar`:

```
case Expr ee:binaryOperation(Expr e1, Expr e2, Op opern) :
```

This should come below the first case. I'm not a big fan of ordering dependencies, so this isn't the solution I would use.

Second, you could match this in your conditional. This matches when it is a `scalar`:

```
if(scalar(_) := e1)
```

and this matches when it isn't:

```
if(scalar(_) !:= e1)
```

If you need the contents -- the value inside `scalar` -- you would want to put a variable in there to bind it in the match.

Third, you could use the `is` operator:

```
if(e1 is scalar)
```

or

```
if (!(e1 is scalar))
```

would let you check whether `e1` is, or is not, constructed using `scalar`. The `is` operator really says "the top constructor for `e1` is `scalar`", and if that is all you need to know, that is simpler than writing a match.

Comment: thanks! so obvious and yet elusive. I kept trying to write if(e1:=scalar(_)), but I don't think that worked. Why is the ordering of e1 and scalar important during pattern matching, or is it?

Comment: one way to think about pattern matching is a more general form of assignment. In an assignment expression/statement in most languages you also write the receiving expression on the left and the producing expression on the right. It is the same with the pattern matching operator: pattern on the left, value on the right. The value side computes/constructs new values and the pattern binds/deconstructs them. Examples: `a := 1`, `<a,b> := <1,2>`, `(str name)(a,b) := f(1,2)`

Comment: thanks, but extending the discussion, what is then fundamentally different between an assignment and pattern binding?